# How to open pptx, docx, pdf , doc files in flutter iOS and Android?

Tags: flutter, file

My files come from a server.

I have tried using open_file plugin by first downloading the files to temp storage but it only saves the files offline in iOS. I also tried flutter_filereader plugin but it is not allowed on AppStore because uses a Chinese engine.

I have also tried webview with the below url scheme but google drive is unresponsive and need to reload 3 or 4 times.

```
 "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=${widget.resourcePath}"
```

Any help or suggestions would be helpful

Comment: What do you mean with "only saves files offline in iOS"? And just for clarification, when you mean open, do you mean "open with appropriate native app" or do you mean "open to render the file in a view in your flutter app"?

Comment: Hello @Robert Sandberg,
by "only saves files offline iOS", whenever i try to open any file, it just asks me where i should be saving the file inside the app, that's it.(This is in iOS simulator, i think the behaviour will be same in real device too). 
And by "Open", anything is fine actually. I'm okay if it can render the files inside the app or open any native viewer. I just need to display the documents.